# Where can I use "new Zend_Form()"?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form-element

in my application where i can invoke statement like `$form = new Zend_Form();` 
i saw that in  controller but why? why use that in controller if we can use application/forms/someform

```
class CustomForm extend Zend_Form
{
    public function init()
    {

    }
}
```

is creating form in controller right? is that hurt MVC architecture? where i can use `$form = new Zend_Form();` except controller and how i can invoke that in view? Im noob in Zend.Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually you create the form in the controller and pass it to the view. In the view you will render the form.

Comment: thanks for answer. how do you think: where better claim new form, in controller or in application/forms/someform ?

Comment: @user1506183: That is up to you. If the application gets big, application/forms might be better.